# Mysql 5.7 - get multiple values from sub select

Tags: mysql

In the query below I am "JOINING" another table where `i.isPrimary > 0` and if all `i.isPrimary` are `0` I just get the first result.

The result set from the query is as expected, but I want to bring more values from each subselect.
I am getting the error: `SQL Error (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

How can this query be rewritten in order to get more results from each subselect?

Thanks

```
-- borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/q/7745609/808921

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ResearchEntity` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name`  varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ResearchEntity` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'one'),
  ('2', 'two'),
  ('3', 'three');
  
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ProfileImageEntity` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `isPrimary` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `researchId` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ProfileImageEntity` (`id`,`isPrimary`, `value`,`researchId`) VALUES
  ('1', 0, 'not primary',1),
  ('2', 0, 'not primary',1),
  ('3', 1, 'primary!!!',1),
  
  ('4', 0, 'primary!!!',2),
  ('5', 0, 'not primary',2),
  ('6', 0, 'not primary',2)
  
  ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UserNameEntity` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `isPrimary` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `researchId` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `UserNameEntity` (`id`,`isPrimary`, `value`,`researchId`) VALUES
  ('1', 0, 'first one, should be returned',1),
  ('2', 0, 'not primary',1),
  ('3', 0, 'primary',1),
  
  ('4', 1, 'primary',3),
  ('5', 0, 'not primary',3),
  ('6', 0, 'not primary',3);
```

SQL FIDDLE
: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/028218/1

```
SELECT r.*,
 (SELECT i.id FROM ProfileImageEntity i WHERE i.researchId = r.id ORDER BY i.isPrimary DESC, i.id ASC  LIMIT 1 ) AS primaryImageId,
       
 (SELECT i.id FROM UserNameEntity i WHERE i.researchId = r.id ORDER BY i.isPrimary DESC, i.id ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS primaryImageId

FROM ResearchEntity r
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry - added http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/028218/1

Comment: What output you are expecting from sample data?

Comment: @AkhileshMishra - the tables `ProfileImageEntity` and `UserNameEntity` has a `value` column, I want to add that to the results. `primaryImageId, primaryImageValue primaryUserNameId, primaryUserNameValue`  thanks

Comment: What I understood from your question and comment the you want more columns from sub Query which is not possible.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra - thats correct. I assume that a join would work better. but the query is tricky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question and comment that you want more columns from sub Query which is not possible. So try this query:

It is easy in MySql 8 but you are using MySql 5.7 where it a little bit tricky So try this:

```
select 
t1.*, 
t2.id AS primaryImageId, 
t2.value AS primaryImageValue, 
t3.id AS primaryUserId,
t3.value AS primaryUserValue
from ResearchEntity t1 

left join ( 

  SELECT    *,
              IF(researchId=@last,@_seq:=@_seq+1,@_seq:=1) AS rn,
              @last:=researchId
    FROM      ProfileImageEntity , (SELECT @_seq:=1, @last:=0) r
    ORDER BY  researchId,isPrimary DESC, id ASC 
   
   ) t2 on t1.id=t2.researchId and t2.rn=1

left join (
  SELECT    *,
              IF(researchId=@last,@_seq:=@_seq+1,@_seq:=1) AS rn,
              @last:=researchId
    FROM      UserNameEntity , (SELECT @_seq:=1, @last:=0) r
    ORDER BY  researchId,isPrimary DESC, id ASC 
   ) t3 on t1.id=t3.researchId and t3.rn=1
   
   order by t1.id
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dfc1dfe1f8d17098020db1bae1442c41)

In MySql 8 using `row_number()`

```
with cte as (
SELECT  *,
row_number() over (partition by researchId ORDER BY isPrimary DESC, id ASC) rn
FROM ProfileImageEntity
),

cte1 as (
sELECT  *,
row_number() over (partition by researchId ORDER BY  isPrimary DESC, id ASC) rn
FROM UserNameEntity
)

select 
t1.*, 
t2.id AS primaryImageId, 
t2.value AS primaryImageValue, 
t3.id AS primaryUserId,
t3.value AS primaryUserValue
from ResearchEntity t1 left join cte t2 on t1.id=t2.researchId and t2.rn=1

left join cte1 t3 on t1.id=t3.researchId and t3.rn=1
```

Comment: Bingo. thanks. in mysql8, how is that more simple? thanks again!

Comment: I have added the query for MySql 8.

Answer (score 0):

try left join

```
SELECT r.*,i.id FROM ResearchEntity r left join ProfileImageEntity i on r.id = i.researchId 
ORDER BY  i.isPrimary,i.id DESC;
```

Comment: This cant work with multiple joined tables like my query

Answer (score 0):

you just need to left join 2 times

```
SELECT r.*,i.id,j.id FROM ResearchEntity r left join ProfileImageEntity i on r.id = i.researchId left join UserNameEntity j on r.id=j.researchId  ORDER BY  i.isPrimary,i.id DESC;
```